# How do I install cv?

Tags: wordpress, cli

I'm trying to install the TurfCutter extension: https://gitlab.com/asludds/civicrm-turfcutter Since I can't install it via the Web UI, I'm struggling.  I managed to get the npm utility installed and `npm install` seemed to work but TurfCutter doesn't show up as an extension.  The TurfCutter install instructions use a `cv` command and I can't get that installed because the instructions for installing cv use `sudo` commands, which DreamHost doesn't allow in my VPS. I tried unzipping cv into .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin  It's there but I guess it needs to be installed.  How do I do that?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded cv.phar from https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/cli-cv/
Then I uploaded cv.phar to .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/
Then I was able to do the shell command: php cv.phar en TurfCutter
That made TurfCutter show up as one of my Extensions. Sadly, I've got it installed and the menu item shows up but I don't think it's working yet...ugh...anyone know TurfCutter?